# filtering in Kendo Grid in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I am trying to add functionality (adding filters to Kendo Grid), to an existing kendo MVC grid. Please see below code of the Grid. I added filters for each column, but not able to get the filtered results. Please let me know any changes to code.

Thanks in advance.

'''

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
         {
            columns.Bound(p => p.RankNumber).Title("Rank").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)); ;
           columns.Bound(p => p.IDSRequestID).Title("ID").ClientTemplate("#if(IDSRequestID>0){#" +
                                                                      "<a target='_blank' href = 

        '" + Url.Action("Edit", "ServiceCatalog") + "?id=#=IDSRequestID#'>#= IDSRequestID#</a>" +
                                                                          "<input type='hidden' 
           name='RankStatus' value='#= RankStatus#'/>" +
                                                                          "#}else {# <span 
           class='hiddenRow'></span>#}#").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitName).Title("Unit Name").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.TeamName).Title("Team Name").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.EffortLeft).Title("Effort Left").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true)); ;
            columns.Bound(p => p.CustName).Title("Customer Name").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
            columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Title("Status").Width(80).Filterable(ftb => 
            ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));


            columns.Bound(p => p.SegmentServiced).Title("Segment Serviced").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductClass).Title("Product Class").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Projects).Title("Projects").Hidden();
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.RankStatus))
        ).Events(e => e.DataBound("GroupCollapse_user")))

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi since you are anyways adding filtering for all coulmns (non hidden columns)..Can you try like this and see if it works

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
         {
            columns.Bound(p => p.RankNumber).Title("Rank").Width(80); 
           columns.Bound(p => p.IDSRequestID).Title("ID").ClientTemplate("#if(IDSRequestID>0){#" +
                                                                      "<a target='_blank' href = 

        '" + Url.Action("Edit", "ServiceCatalog") + "?id=#=IDSRequestID#'>#= IDSRequestID#</a>" +
                                                                          "<input type='hidden' 
           name='RankStatus' value='#= RankStatus#'/>" +
                                                                          "#}else {# <span 
           class='hiddenRow'></span>#}#").Width(80); 
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitName).Title("Unit Name").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.TeamName).Title("Team Name").Width(80); 
            columns.Bound(p => p.EffortLeft).Title("Effort Left").Width(80); 
            columns.Bound(p => p.CustName).Title("Customer Name").Width(80);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Title("Status").Width(80);


            columns.Bound(p => p.SegmentServiced).Title("Segment Serviced").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductClass).Title("Product Class").Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.Projects).Title("Projects").Hidden();
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.RankStatus))
        ).Events(e => e.DataBound("GroupCollapse_user")))
```